# Solve this geometry problem without using any trigonometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given:
$ \triangle ABC $
$AC = BC$
$\angle C = 150$
$AB (base) = \sqrt{12}$
Find the radius of the Circumcircle.
I have no idea how to solve this challenge, the answer which is given in the textbook is $2\sqrt{3}$ (which is the base).

**P.S.** The textbook is for 8th grade, and in my country, sin and cosine law are learned in 9th grade(next year). So proofs without trigonometry are preferred.

Comment: By sine law $\displaystyle \frac{BC}{\sin(\angle{ACB})}=2R$.

Comment: is there any other way since the textbook is for 8th grade, and in my country sin and cosine law are learned in 9th grade(next year).

Comment: @namel4ss include it in your question. Also, edit the title so that it provides information about your problem. This way your question will get more attention.

Comment: @namel4ss I edited your question according to the comments. Check if it is okay.

Comment: Yes thank you. I was just editing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the figure, since $\angle{BCA} = 150$, we have $$\angle{BDA} = 180-150 = 30 \,\,\, (\because \text{Cyclic quadrilateral }ACBD)$$ and therefore $$\angle{BOA} = 2\times 30 = 60 \,\,\, (\because \text{Central angle is twice the inscribed angle})$$ Hence, $\Delta AOB$ is equilateral.

This is because $OA = OB \implies $base angles are equal, which inturn $\implies$ that all angles are $60$, which in turn $\implies$ the triangle is equiangular, which inturn $\implies$ the triangle $AOB$ is also equilateral.

Hence, the circumradius is $AB = \sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt3$.

[image]

Comment: Great answer (+1)

Comment: Yours along with Christian's answer, employing similar concepts are very very good answers. +1 to both.

Answer (score 8):

Consider $AC$ and $CB$ as two successive sides of a regular dodecagon inscribed in some circle $\gamma$. $AB$ is then the side of a regular hexagon inscribed in  $\gamma$, hence equal to the radius of $\gamma$. Since $\gamma$ is also the circumcircle of $\triangle(ABC)$ the claim follows.

Comment: Wow !. You made it look so obvious without the use of any trigonometry. +1

Answer (score 1):

$$R=\frac{c}{2\sin(150^\circ)}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=2\sqrt{3}$$